# I'm using nest If statements and For Next statements to retrieve and change data in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

For some reason everyday of the week is being filled with "Timed". I'm testing for a null value, but it doesn't seem to be seeing any values in the table

I am using a DLookup to test if the value is true, seems to be working fine.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim wc As DAO.Recordset
Dim stc As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set wc = db.OpenRecordset("Weekly_Challenges")
Set stc = db.OpenRecordset("Weekly_StartTime_Challenges")

amRoutine = DLookup("AMRoutineStartTime", "Standard_Actions", "UserId=" & Me.UserID.Value & " And WeekNumber=" & Me.WeekNumber)

If Form_Weekly_Challenges_subform.StandardAction.Value = "AM Routine" Then
    If amRoutine = -1 Then
        For i = 0 To stc.RecordCount - 1
        If stc.Fields("StartTimeAction") = "AM Routine" Then
            For j = 0 To wc.RecordCount - 1
                If wc.Fields("StandardAction") = "AM Routine" Then
                    If stc.Fields("Monday") = Null Then
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Monday") = ""
                    wc.Update
                    Else
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Monday") = "Timed"
                    wc.Update
                    End If
                    If stc.Fields("Tuesday") = Null Then
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Tuesday") = ""
                    wc.Update
                    Else
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Tuesday") = "Timed"
                    wc.Update
                    End If
                    If stc.Fields("Wednesday") = Null Then
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Wednesday") = ""
                    wc.Update
                    Else
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Wednesday") = "Timed"
                    wc.Update
                    End If
                    If stc.Fields("Thursday") = Null Then
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Thursday") = ""
                    wc.Update
                    Else
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Thursday") = "Timed"
                    wc.Update
                    End If
                    If stc.Fields("Friday") = Null Then
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Friday") = ""
                    wc.Update
                    Else
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Friday") = "Timed"
                    wc.Update
                    End If
                    If stc.Fields("Saturday") = Null Then
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Saturday") = ""
                    wc.Update
                    Else
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Saturday") = "Timed"
                    wc.Update
                    End If
                    If stc.Fields("Sunday") = Null Then
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Sunday") = ""
                    wc.Update
                    Else
                    wc.Edit
                    wc.Fields("Sunday") = "Timed"
                    wc.Update
                    End If
                End If
            wc.MoveNext
            Next j
        End If
        stc.MoveNext
        Next i
        End If
     Else
End If
```

Monday, Wednesday, and Friday should have "Timed" and the rest should be empty

Comment: You cannot test `Null` with `=`, any test with `Null`is always `Null`, not `True` and the test will evaluate to False. To test `Null` values, use [IsNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnull-function).

Comment: Leave the _Null_ values. You should never (try to) store zero-length strings unless for some very good and specific reason.